# Disable touchpad on tablet

Tags: windows-7, drivers, mouse, touchpad

I use a tablet PC and I use the touch screen for navigating, so I would like to permanently disable the touchpad on the laptop. I've tried a few things but nothing seems to work.

I've tried uninstalling and disabling the driver, uninstalling caused it to be reinstalled on reboot, and windows 7 won't let me disable it from device manager. I also tried a couple apps that disable the pad while typing, but I want to disable it permanently, not just while typing.

The laptop in an HP TouchSmart tm2.

Any ideas on how else I can disable the touchpad?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Bluetooth mouse so I don't want the touch pad to stay enabled since it's very sensitive and disturbs my typing. Here's where I find the option to disable it:

- Administrador de dispositivos (Device Manager)

  - Mouse y otros dispositivos señalizadores (Mice and pointing devices)

    - Deshabilitar (Right click, disable device)

There should be two devices shown, the Bluetooth mouse and the integrated touchpad, so try one of then (If it's not the right one, re-enable and disable the second).

Comment: This is a great answer, even if your native language isn't English. Thank you for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

Device Manager from the control panel -> system -> hardware tab -> Device Manager. Go to the "human interface devices" then go to the "touch panel driver" and right click on it. Then choose "Disable".

Alternatively go into the Synaptics settings and disable all of the multi-touch features individually.

Failing that try rolling it back to an older driver and follow above.

Comment: There is no "touch panel driver"

there is a whole bunch of HID-compliant devices, a microsoft input configuration device, a wacom guesture touch, a wacom pen, and a wacom virtual hid driver.

I don't have any Synaptics settings anywhere.

Where would I go to roll back to an older driver?